# New quantum algorithm for approximating permanent

Tags: quantum-computing, permanent

Joonsuk Huh uploaded a paper "[A fast quantum algorithm for computing matrix permanent](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.01328)
" on arxiv, which claims a polynomial-time algorithm approximating the permanent of an arbitrary matrix with multiplicative and additive errors.

Given the $\#P$-hardness result of approximating permanent, the result implies striking complexity consequences, such as $P^{\#P} \subset BQP$ and $BPP \neq BQP$ (assuming $PH$ does not collapse), as the paper explicitly states.

I skimmed the first few pages and found some interesting lines, e.g., the Glynn-Kan formula (Eqn. (6), named by the author), but unable to follow all details.

I am wondering if the status or discussions of this paper. Is there any discussion on this paper, or does anyone verify the results?

Comment: We are all waiting for Aaronson's blog post :)

Comment: He's already commented on it: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6405#comment-1939064 https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6405#comment-1939221